# how to verify that cmu font family does have half point size fonts

Tags: fontsize

I am trying to typeset a document using cmu 10.5 pt. I downloaded and installed the cmu fonts in Windows 10.

The journal template including fonts is available from http://www.lajss.org/howtos/template_lajss.zip

I am using pdflatex to compile through TeXstudio. In the MWE below, setting \fontsize{10.5}{12} has the same effect as \fontsize{11}{12}, and \fontsize{10}{12} makes the font too small. The four commented lines have no effect if I uncomment them. What am I doing wrong?

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\begin{document}
%\fontencoding{OT1}
%\fontfamily{cmu}
%\fontseries{m}
%\fontshape{rm}
\fontsize{10.5}{12}\selectfont
\noindent This template is typeset using the format adopted by the Latin 
 American Journal of Solids and Structures. The fonts used can be download 
in the site and they are subject to the open source regulations. The fonts 
should be be installed in the folder used by the system to store this type
of file.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

After you install the fonts as system fonts (but there is a newer version in TeX Live), you just type

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{CMU Serif}

\begin{document}

\noindent This template is typeset using the format adopted by the Latin
 American Journal of Solids and Structures. The fonts used can be download
in the site and they are subject to the open source regulations. The fonts
should be be installed in the folder used by the system to store this type
of file.\fontname\font

\fontsize{10.5}{12}\selectfont
\noindent This template is typeset using the format adopted by the Latin
 American Journal of Solids and Structures. The fonts used can be download
in the site and they are subject to the open source regulations. The fonts
should be be installed in the folder used by the system to store this type
of file.\fontname\font

\end{document}
```

and compile with either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX. Not `pdflatex`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As posted your document produces

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/cmr/m/n' in size <10.5> not available
(Font)              size <10.95> substituted on input line 7.
```

If you want to allow cmr at any size, add

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
```

as the first line.

so:

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass[]{article}
\begin{document}
\fontencoding{T1}
\fontsize{10.5}{12}\selectfont
\noindent This template is typeset using the format adopted by the Latin 
 American Journal of Solids and Structures. The fonts used can be download 
in the site and they are subject to the open source regulations. The fonts 
should be be installed in the folder used by the system to store this type
of file.
\end{document}
```

---

I just looked at the template (having found it) the cm-unicode fonts are really just intended for Word as far as I can see, for latex you can use the standard cm fonts, scaled to any size using `fix-cm` package.

---

**older answer parts:**

But you want to use cmu so

uncommenting the cmu line the warning changes to

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/cmu/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `OT1/cmr/m/n' instead on input line 7.
```

which means that cmu isn't available at all.

the only fonts I would associate with the name "CMU" are the CM Unicode fonts available in Opentype format for use with luatex and xetex are the latex fd files for  available in OT1 or T1 encoded versions of these?

```
\fontshape{rm}
```

should be

```
\fontshape{n}
```

`rm` is not the name of a shape in the latex font scheme.

---

Barbara in comments suggest that by cmu you may have meant the cm unslanted italic, which is a font shape not a font family, The shape `ui`, even though the fonts are `cmu10.tfm`

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass[]{article}
\begin{document}
%\fontencoding{OT1}
\fontshape{ui}
\fontsize{10.5}{12}\selectfont
\noindent This template is typeset using the format adopted by the Latin 
 American Journal of Solids and Structures. The fonts used can be download 
in the site and they are subject to the open source regulations. The fonts 
should be be installed in the folder used by the system to store this type
of file.
\end{document}
```

Comment: not only cm-unicode.  the original `cmu` is "computer modern unslanted italic".  it comes designed only in 10pt.  of course, a type1 version can be scaled, but probably nobody has done that..

Comment: @barbarabeeton oh yes that one. But that isn't a font family. ah.... perhaps this is a correct answer to a wrong question.....

Comment: @barbarabeeton updated answer ^^^^